# How can I snap to grid a value between 0 and 1

Tags: math, graphics

let's say I have a value that is between `0` and `1`. I have a grid size and would like the value to snap to grid. so if grid size is equal to two I would like to switch from `0` to `1` if grid size equal to three this would switch from `0`, `0.5` to `1` if it's four `0`, `0.33`, `0.66`, `1` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the language you use has a `round` function that rounds to the nearest integer, and calling `v` the value and `n` the grid size:

```
round(v * (n-1)) / (n-1)
```